# count but small bug

Tags: c++, token, stringtokenizer

I am doing separate one string , I do add one case when see the delimilator, It works fine for the last delimilator . For example my string is `"symbol control_line : std_logic:= '0' ; --example comment"` The output is correct when see the first delimilator : but when It look at the second := it failed. I do not know why it happens? The code should be fine for both delimilator how come just figure out the first , but failed the second?

This prepareNextToken function is figure out what is the tokenLength of second Token. And I can use this function to get what the current token.

```
void Tokenizer::prepareNextToken()
{
        string real=*str;
        if(offset==real.size())
            complete=true;
        else
        {
            if(ifcomment==false)
            {
                size_t length=0;
                size_t index=offset;
                size_t smallest=find_first_delimilater(vhdl_char);
                while(index<real.size() )
                {
                    length++;
                    if(index==smallest && real[index+1]==' ')
                    {
                        cout<<real[smallest]<<" ";
                       break;
                    }
                    else if(index==smallest && real[index+1]!=' ')
                    {
                        length++;
                       break;
                    }
                    else if(index==real.find(' ',offset))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(index==real.find("--",offset))
                    {
                        length++;
                       break;
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                tokenLength=length;
            }
            else if(ifcomment==true)
                tokenLength=real.size()-offset;
        }
        //cout<<tokenLength<<endl;
}
```

my output is

```
    signal            --which is correct
    control_line      --the current offset
    :                 --which is right because I reach the first case in my    
                      --prepareNextToken and ":" is first delimilator
    std_logic:=       --that is the wrong output because it should be std_logic
                      -- and in a separate line comes out ";=" which is another 
                      --delimilator, and is a multiple delimilator no empty case 
                      -- so that means I go to the second cases 
   --                 -- which is also right which go to fourth case
   sample comment    -- which is right
```

And my question is why when ":" comes out it in its own line , but why ":=" comes out it ends with std_logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `substr` is the number of characters to be extracted rather than the end position (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).
So your extraction line should be:

```
s=name.substr(offset,tokenLength);
```

Comment: But now I comes to another question. Can you have a look? :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure about the rules here, but I'm pretty sure you have to open a new question rather than reuse a previous one... You might notice that my answer is completely off-topic now... You should revert to the original question, and post this new one...  in a new thread :-) I'll give it a look as soon as it's up.